# What is "sound understanding" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

What is a German expression for *sound understanding* as in:

> Do you have a 'sound understanding' of Software Architecture and Artifical Intelligence?

Comment: Could you please add, in what way your dictionary wasn't helpful? Is it the usage of _sound_ as an adjective, instead of a noun? Or something else maybe?

Comment: https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/de/Do%20you%20have%20a%20'sound%20understanding'%20of%20Software%20Architecture%20and%20Artifical%20Intelligence%3F

Comment: The English word *sound* has to be translated as *tief* here. Don't be confused, it doesn't mean *low* here but *deep*.

Comment: @Storm, you don't need to accept the first answer. It's usually better to wait a  bit and see which answer get's the most upvotes.

Comment: I don't know what sound is supposed to mean in English in this case. For some reason the word "sund" in Swedish rings me a bell, but it means more like "healthy". Do you mean healthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Janka in his/her comment stated, "tief" (im Sinne von *vertiefen*) would be the best translation here. So *a sound understanding* translates to *"ein tiefes Verständnis"*. Alternatively *weitreichend, zuverlässig, erfahren, erprobt* or *versiert* could be used.

Answer (score 6):

The adjective *sound* in this context could translate as any of the following:

> solide, gut, sicher, gründlich, fundiert; umfassend, umfangreich, tiefschürfend; breit gefächert

In the context of job applications, there are often subtle distinctions that are only discernible to those working in human relations. Not being privy to that, I find it hard to estimate what level of competence is indicated by *sound*; if it is on the lower end of the spectrum, *solide* would fit, if it is on the higher end, *umfangreich*. *Breit gefächert* suggests *breadth of knowledge*.

Although *understanding* literally means *Verständnis*, I feel that in the context of a job application, it could also be *Kenntnisse*.

> Haben Sie solide, gründliche, fundierte Kenntnisse in Bezug auf Softwareentwicklung und Künstliche Intelligenz?

Having written all that by hand, I see that the following website automatically generates, at least in this case, a pretty good overview regarding possible translations: [link](https://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/sound+understanding.html).

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary from google search tells me sound means

```
"in good condition; not damaged, injured, or diseased. "they returned safe and sound"
```

Cognate to swedish "sund". In german, I would go with "gesund".

Same dictionary even claims "sound" likely comes from old-english "gesund" (same word as today's german!?).